# Charging one plate of capacitor and grounding the other plate of capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, earth, batteries

I want to learn about this way of charging the capacitor. At my university, we charge capacitor with power supply. Its negative power supply. Power supply is grounded (earthed). A conductor from power supply is attached to one plate of capacitor and other plate of capacitor is grounded (earthed) separately. Both earthed points are different  (physically). I want to learn how this capacitor is getting charged?

Answer (score 4):

> Both earthed points are different (physically). I want to learn how
> this capacitor is getting charged

The fact that the power supply and one plate of the capacitor are earth grounded at different locations simply potentially introduces additional resistance through which charging occurs. That resistance increases the charging time constant (t=RC) slowing down the rate of charging the capacitor. How slow for a given capacitance C depends on how much resistance exists between the earth connection of the power supply and the earth connection of the one plate, which in turn depends on the conductivity of the soil and the distance between the connections.

Perhaps the diagram below illustrates your university experiment. It assumes there is no other resistor connected between the power supply and the capacitor, i.e., the only resistance is the soil between the earth connections and the resistance of the connecting wires is negligible. Under these conditions if the capacitor is initially uncharged, and the switch shown closes at time $t=0$, the theoretical voltage across the capacitor as a function of time, $V_{C}(t)$, would be

$$V_{C}(t)= V(1-e^{-t/RC})$$

If your experiment involved another resistor connected between the power supply and capacitor, you would need to add it to the value of $R$ in the above equation.

> I want to add a further question. What would happen if we remove the
> supply and connect a ground stick (connected to another separate
> ground) at the positive terminal of the capacitor shown in the figure
> above. How would a charged capacitor behave in this scenario?

The capacitor will discharge through the ground. In this case the voltage across the capacitor as a function of time will be $$V_{C}(t)=V_{o}\epsilon ^{-t/RC}$$ where $V_{o}$ is the initial voltage across the capacitor.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot Bob D. I want to add a further question. What would happen if we remove the supply and connect a ground stick (connected to another separate ground) at the positive terminal of the capacitor shown in the figure above. How would a charged capacitor behave in this scenario?

Comment: Are you asking what would happen if you started with a charged capacitor and connected both the positive and negative plates to earth with separate grounding electrodes?

Comment: Exactly. I am asking the same.

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilNawaz I have updated my answer to respond to your additional question.

Comment: @BobD it would discharge even faster, as the earth grounding acts as an infinite sink for charge, it does not path the discharge only through the measured soil resistance R between the contacts.

Comment: @PcMan For the capacitor to discharge the soil has to remove electrons from the negative plate and deposit electrons on the positive plate. That means electrons have to flow to and from the electrons through the soil. The soil is not  zero resistance.

Comment: Can we have a rough value of soil resistance if we suppose the two separate grounding points 10 meters apart ?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilNawaz Soil resistance varies all over the map. It depends not only on the composition of the soil but moisture content as well as degree of salinity. To give you an idea of the range of values, take a look at this: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-ranges-of-electrical-resistivity-and-conductivity-of-earth-material-Samouelian_fig1_263506005

Comment: Thanks alot bob. I would like to ask another question in this thread. In the case that both plates of capacitor are connected to separate grounds. How wiill you describe the charge flow ? I mean is the charge flowing from negative plate to capacitor to the postive plate of capacitor via soil OR Soil being the infinite sink is providing positive charges to negative plate of capacitor and negative charges to positive plate of capacitor?

Comment: @BobD You are still wrong. By your theory, if one connects those two ground elements 10000km apart, the capacitor will take millions of years to discharge. Two ground spikes do *not* act like a normal conductor with a resistor between them. Each ground acts as an infinite pool of (roughly) zero voltage, capable of accepting or donating any number of electrons without changing its voltage.

Comment: @PcMan can you answer the sceniorio i have explained in the last comment ?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilNawaz There are many factors involved. For a thorough discussion see: https://blog.nvent.com/erico-what-is-soil-resistivity-and-how-does-it-affect-grounding/

Comment: @PcMan I don't know what "theory" you are referring to, but all I am saying is there is resistance to current flow between the electrodes. I didn't say how much, or how it depends on the distance between them (increase or decrease) or the soil resistivity. Or, for that matter,  that one of the most important things is the resistance of the soil that in direct contact with the electrodes.